# HTML IMA SDK - Custom click through

Tags: video.js, vast, imasdk

**Requirement:**
Show the Visit Website link for the VAST clickThrough. By default in we desktop, whole ima3 container is clickable and redirecting to clickThrough url. Is there anyway to show the clickThrough url like youtube? 
[image]

**Note**
I have tried with custom click element. But it will only for web mobile. In the web desktop it won't work.

**Demo Link:**
codepen.io/anon/pen/jvVpvR

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on this ticket, the user seem to contact goolgle ima sdk, and they say that is just not possible

https://groups.google.com/g/ima-sdk/c/xqDZvXuSJLE?pli=1